# Creating a Distributed Account System with MacOS

Tags: macos, unix

We have tens of Mac computers and hundreds of students in our lab. Each student will have a G Suite education account.

We somehow want to achieve a solution so that:

1. Each student will have a private account (email, password)
2. Each student will be able to login from any MacOS with that account.

**How close we can get to this scenario?**

I'm ready to install supportive servers if there is a way to distribute accounts across lab computers.

**UPDATE**

What we want is to provide 1GB of disk space for each user. So I started to think like this:

- I can set a central server which has a volume for each student. Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer after long research.

There's a project called OpenLDAP, which also runs on Docker. When you configure mac authentication to listen to the ldap server, users can log in to any Mac any time.

https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap

There's only one "con", you can't limit disk quotas, which is OK. This is the best closest solution. I plan to add cloud options (e.g: owncloud) for users; which will help us as extra disk space.